# How do I make the first registered user an administrator on the Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User model, my application on Rails 5 and I'm trying to make a custom callback that allows you to assign the role of admin to the first registered user, but unfortunately, when saving data to the database, the role is not assigned... Tell me please, what's wrong?

Database

```
t.boolean "admin", default: false
```

Model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_save: update_admin
  
private
  def update_admin
    User.count(1).update_attributes (admin: 'true')
   end
end
```

Comment: you should use the find method, not the count. `User.find (1) .update_attributes (admin: true)` . But I think you want to do this only once from the rails console, not every time a user is saved.

Comment: Unfortunately did not help ...  ```=> #<User id: 1, created_at: "2018-05-10 13:40:46", updated_at: "2018-05-10 13:40:46", email: "re@ya.com", admin: false, name: "First"> ```

Comment: You have failing validations? Check `user.errors.messages` to see the error (if `user` is the first user for which the `update_attributes` failed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a `before_create` callback that will *set* `admin` to `true` (but not save! it would trigger the `before_save` callback again and so on => Stack level too deep).

You can do the following:

```
before_create :set_admin

private

def set_admin
  self.admin = true unless User.exists? # faster than a count
end
```

Or the alternative version, with an `after_save` callback:

```
after_create :update_admin

private

def update_admin
  self.update_attributes!(admin: true) if User.count == 1
end
```

The downside of both solutions is that these callbacks will trigger a SQL count each time you create a User.

Comment: Thank you so much! I used the second option!

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
user = User.find(1)
user.admin = true
user.save
```

I wouldn't recommend using Callback for updating 1st registered user as admin. You can use seeds as it needs to be run only one time.

Comment: For clarity: you should run this in the `rails console` and maybe your first/only user does not have id=1? So try `user = User.first` as the first line should work. I prefer this "manual approach" over callbacks for what essentially should be an exceptional case (e.g. making sure you are the admin)